Notification Bot: empty installation list when deployed on Linux
I'm developing a notification bot for Microsoft Teams using Node.js and deploying it to Azure App Service/Bot Service. The bot works fine when hosted on a Windows environment in Azure. However, if I deploy the same bot/service hosting to a Linux environment, the bot is unable to retrieve the list of installations, it always returns empty array. Could I be missing some permissions? The permissions are the same as those used for the Windows hosting.
I'm using the ConversationBot class for handling bot installations.
export const notificationApp = new ConversationBot({
  adapterConfig: {
    MicrosoftAppId: config.botId,
    MicrosoftAppPassword: config.botPassword,
    MicrosoftAppType: "MultiTenant",
  },
  notification: {
    enabled: true,
  },
});

const installationsPagedData = await notificationApp.notification.getPagedInstallations(pageSize, continuationToken);

The only changes I have made are in azure.bicep file. For the serverfarm resource:
// Windows hosting
resource serverfarm 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
  kind: 'app'
  location: location
  name: serverfarmsName
  sku: {
    name: webAppSKU
  }
}

// Linux hosting
resource serverfarm 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: serverfarmsName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: webAppSKU
  }
  kind: 'linux'
  properties: {
    reserved: true   // Reserved should be true for Linux-based hosting
  }
}

And for the sites resource I add 'linuxFxVersion' in properties - siteConfig:
resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  kind: 'app,linux'
  location: location
  name: webAppName
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: serverfarm.id
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      alwaysOn: true
      linuxFxVersion: 'NODE|18-lts'
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
          value: '1' 
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
          value: '~18'
        }
        {
          name: 'BOT_ID'
          value: botAadAppClientId
        }
        {
          name: 'BOT_PASSWORD'
          value: botAadAppClientSecret
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

I added the bot as a custom app in a chat in Teams, I expect to retrieve a non-empty installation list, on linux as well as on windows.
Thanks!

Could you share the expected output of installationsPagedData ? Is it possible that the chat bot app hosted on Linux doesn't yet have any installations, hence it returns empty list?
